# Query parent table and get child tables columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, select, inheritance

I have two tables, one inherits the other:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    col1 INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    col2 INTEGER
) INHERITS( parent );

// Insert some data
INSERT INTO parent( col1 ) VALUES( 1 );
INSERT INTO child( col1, col2 ) VALUES( 2, 2 );
```

Is there any way to query the parent table, such that it gets all of the columns of the child tables?

This query returns just the parent columns:

```
SELECT * FROM parent;

| col1 |
| ---- |
| 1    |
| 2    |
```

My desired query would return all columns in parent and child:

```
SELECT ...  -- some query, with desired result:

| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| 1    | NULL |
| 2    | 2    |
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the set of inherited column values is unique across all tables, there is a simple solution with a **`NATURAL`** join (one of the rare use cases for this clause!):

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY parent NATURAL FULL JOIN child;
```

Since `NATURAL` is ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)):

> ... shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in the two tables that have the same names.

You get each column only once without explicit `SELECT` list, and rows from the parent table are extended with NULL values for added columns - exactly the way you desire.

This even works with NULL values in any of the columns.

To also [see the ***origin*** of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576324/939860) in the result, let's add another row to your test case:

```
INSERT INTO child(col1) VALUES(1);
```

Then:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.tableoid, c.tableoid)::regclass AS tbl, *
FROM   ONLY parent p NATURAL FULL JOIN child c;

 tbl   | col1 | col2
-------+------+----
parent | 1    | NULL
child  | 1    | NULL
child  | 2    | 2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9b6a37c1a5dd6a1a5ca81395755f0126)* - with more test rows
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/207fa/1)</sub>

You can join to **multiple child tables** this way if all additional column ***names*** in all child tables are ***unique***. Else you'll have to spell out an explicit `SELECT` list and explicit join conditions.

The set of inherited column ***values*** has to be unique across all child tables.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you can't by just querying the parent table. The child inherits from the parent but the parent is unaware of the child. A left outer join should get you the desired answer but that involves both tables

```
select p.col1, c.col2 from parent p left outer join child c on c.col1 = p.col1;
```

Comment: This reads the child table twice and fails for NULL values in `col1`. You also have to spell out all columns.